# CSS Grid animations using grid-area

Tags: css, animation, css-grid

I am building a puzzle using CSS grid.

I have simplified the puzzle to a single red tile and a blank tile.

What I am trying to do is if you click on the red tile, the red tile will slide over to the blank tiles position.

At the moment I am able to switch their position using a simple javascript click handler which toggles the class "left" and "right" to both tile divs. Then, in my CSS, I have specified grid-areas (left and right) for the css class `.left` or `.right`.

It's a little hard to explain so I am including all the code below.

Basically, I am hoping to find some way to transition the red tile from `grid-area: left` to `grid-area: right` in a sliding motion.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!!

```js
const red = document.querySelector('.red');
const blank = document.querySelector('.blank');
red.addEventListener('click', slide);

function slide() {
  red.classList.toggle('left');
  red.classList.toggle('right');
  blank.classList.toggle('left');
  blank.classList.toggle('right');
}
```

```css
.container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "left right";
  border: 10px solid black;
  text-align: center;
}

.red {
  background: red;
}

.left {
  grid-area: left;
}

.right {
  grid-area: right;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="red left">
    <p>RED</p>
  </div>
  <div class="blank right"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: You cannot transition grid area values. You would need to calculate the position of the element and adjust to the new proposed position. That will require a fair amount of Javascript.

Comment: Thanks, I found a library that does just that!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a bit of digging, I was able to find a solution to my problem. 
I thought I could share it here incase anyone else is in the same predicament. 
You can find the "Easy transitions for CSS Grid" library here

https://github.com/aholachek/animate-css-grid

I also found a codepen example which demonstrates the exact behavior I was looking for using this library:

https://codepen.io/daviddarnes/pen/EOqZdw

The only small issue I faced was that the white "blank" tile was sliding over the colored tile. 
I simply added `z-index: 1` to my colored tile and `z-index: 0` to my blank tile in my style sheet and voila. Works like a charm!

Note: Neither the library nor codepen program are my own work, I am just sharing these resources with you all in hopes of helping someone out!